# Can an Adjustable Circuit Breaker be adjusted while Energized?

Tags: low-voltage, circuit-breaker

For a Low Voltage Circuit Breaker, such as the [Legrand DPX3 630](https://www.legrand.be/sites/default/files/downloads/NL/Brochures/EXB16053-DPX_60-250-December-2016.pdf), [3x400A, 36kA, 400V](https://www.legrand.com/ecatalogue/422002-mccb-dpx-630-thermal-magnetic.html), we have adjustment dials to change the properties of the magnetic (Magnetic adjustable from 5 to 10 In) and or thermal (Thermal adjustable from 0.8 to 1 In) trip curve.

[image]

In practice this normally don't happen, but, Should be any **damage risk to the breaker** to change those adjustments while the equipment is energized?

Comment: Please, focus on equipment impact, not on operational impact, users loads, connected equipment loads. Only in breaker damage risk.

Comment: What does the manual say? Have you asked the manufacturer how to use the product?

Comment: @Justme  All manuals and specifications so far for these lines and similar do not show any relevant advice about this topic. Representatives in here have not a clear idea about something as specific as this.

Answer (score 3):

No, there should be no risk to the breaker or disconnection of the load unless your adjustment sets the trip point below the actual load. In general the breaker settings can be adjusted under load.

If in doubt check the user manual. If that doesn't have the information you require then call their technical support line. A company like Legrand will actually have one!